# Advantages of using CMake option command rather than set?

Tags: cmake

I think the `option` command is redundant because it can be replaced by the `set` command. What are the benefits I could get when I use the `option` command?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A variable defined in an [`option`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aoption) command appears as a boolean choice in the CMake GUI or when running CMake interactively using [`cmake -i`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#opt%3a-i).  This is not the case for a variable defined using [`set`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aset) unless `CACHE` is used and the type is not `INTERNAL`.

Also, the [`CMakeDependentOption`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#module%3aCMakeDependentOption) module allows for specifying dependencies between options.

Comment: And `option` vs `set CACHE`?

Comment: @CiroSantilli709大抓捕六四事件法轮功 check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358217/cmake-option-vs-set-a-cached-bool-variable)