# What is the difference between "option" and "set CACHE BOOL" for a CMake variable?

Tags: cmake, boolean, global-variables, cmake-gui

Is there any difference between the following two?

```
set(FOO true CACHE BOOL "description")

option(FOO "description" ON)
```

Documentation: [set](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html) - [option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html)

Background: Even if I have been using CMake for a while, I only noticed the `option` command today and I have therefore always been using `set`: I was wondering if it is safe/worth to replace the first with the second.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

In your example, there is no difference. But there can be differences:

- `option` has a default value of `OFF`.
- You can make an option dependent on other options with [`CMakeDependentOption`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeDependentOption.html)
- `set` accepts types other than `BOOL`, especially [;-lists](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#cmake-language-lists).

Additionally, when you use an option you are indicating to your user that it can be set safely. Setting internal variables from the outside might subtly break the script with invalid values.

Comment: Regarding your last point, when using `set`, by making the variable a boolean don't I prevent the user from giving it a different kind of value e.g. in the command line? Anyway, I find your second point pretty relevant.

Comment: Frankly, I haven't ever tried that. But I think I remember CMake GUI adjusts its input method depending on the variable type.

Comment: That I can confirm (for a boolean variable it gives you a tick box)

Comment: However, if you use the command line -D approach, rather than ccmake, CMake is perfectly happy to let you set a BOOL variable/option to non-BOOL values whether you use `option` or `set(...CACHE BOOL)`. So it seems this "type safety" only applies for ccmake/cmake-gui.

Comment: Regarding the first point: `option` accepts an optional initial value. If no initial value is provided, `OFF` is used.

Answer (score 12):

Stumbled on this question, and thought I added an update.

As explained [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html), the `option` command does not create a CACHE variable if a normal variable with the same name exists. This behavior was introduced in version 3.13 (where it is the default). On the other hand, setting a CACHE variable named `FOO` when `FOO` exists as a normal variable, will yield two copies of FOO, a normal variable and a CACHE one.

Therefore, whether to use `option(FOO "" ON)` or `set(FOO ON CACHE BOOL "")` may also depend on what you want your configuration system to do when a variable with the same name has already been defined upstream.

Note: the two still behave the same way if FOO has been defined upstream *in the cache*. The difference is only if the upstream is a *normal* variable.

Comment: You might want to check [CMP0126](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0126.html#policy:CMP0126).