# How to do conditional variable assignment with cmake?

Tags: cmake

I would like to give a default value DEF to a variable VAR if I do not give the flag -DVAR=VAL. Have you any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: `if(not VAR) set(VAR "DEF") endif()` ?

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to work. Thanks to Kamil Cuk which leads me to one solution.

```
if(not defined VAR)
                set(VAR VAL)
 endif()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`set(... CACHE ...)` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-cache-entry):

```perl
set(VAR "DEF" CACHE STRING "My VAR for doing xyz")
```

If the variable is already set in the cache - e.g. via command line switch `-D` - it's not overwritten. And the user could change it with [cmake-gui](/questions/tagged/cmake-gui) or [ccmake](/questions/tagged/ccmake).

Or if you have boolean values take the [`option()` definitions command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html).

**References**

- [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables)
- [What is the difference between "option" and "set CACHE BOOL" for a CMake variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358217/what-is-the-difference-between-option-and-set-cache-bool-for-a-cmake-variabl)